# Either and vs. Either or

Tags: american-english, commas, lists, correlative-conjunctions

(1) In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154337/any-one-of-or-either) on math.SE a question about the meaning of 'either' before a list which ends with 'and'. The meaning of

```
either a, b, c, or d
```

is [from this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/does-either-a-or-b-preclude-both-a-and-b) sort of clear in that it means a or b or c or d. Even if *or* can mean all included, the *either* seems to indicate an exclusivity.  so *exactly* one of them. But what does

```
either a, b, c, and d
```

mean? Is this even current English?

(2) in the same question there is the question about what

```
any one of a, b, c, and d
```

means. So I would also like to know what

```
any one of a, b, c, or d
```

means?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you're right that the correlative conjunction *either ... or ...* is simply a summation of successive *or*'s -- *either ... or  ... or ... or ...*, with only the last *or* obligatory. Same thing without *either*, except that then it's not clear that this is disjunction with *or*, instead of conjunction with *and* (which is more common, and unmarked). But if you start the list with *either* you don't need to include and stress *or* all the time.

*Either ... **and** ...*, on the other hand, is simply wrong, and probably just a typo if written.

The answer to the second question is that

- ***any one of a, b, c, and d*** is mathspeak for *any* (or *some*) *member of the set [a, b, c, d]*

while

- ***any one of a, b, c, or d*** is not mathspeak, but simple enumeration, with "free-choice" *any.*

Comment: What do you mean by "free-choice" any?

Comment: There are at least two different uses of _any_ in English. By far the more common is [Negative Polarity _any_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf); but a different sense implies one may take a choice of some member of a set. NPI _any_ requires a Negative environment, so it's rarely a subject, but free choice _any_ is often a subject, e.g, _"Anybody can learn English in just 10 weeks!"_ which asserts that a person picked at random can do this, which in turn implies that everyone can do this. Including oneself, one is sposta conclude.

Comment: I wouldn't read *any one of* to include *or some of*, regardless of conjunction; I would take the *one* to mean you have to pick just one. *Any of*, on the other hand, I would assume included the possibility of more than one, up to all. I'm not a mathematician, though.

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding of *"either a, b, c or d"* is correct. But with *either*, we never use **and**. Hence *"either a, b, c and d"* is **incorrect**.

> *"any one of a, b, c or d"* means **one among a, b, c, and d**.
>
> *"any one of a, b, c and d"* seems vague.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a mathematician, and I'd just like to confirm that, although some of us have a reputation for mangling the English language, I've never encountered the "either ... and ..." mangling before. I'm inclined to assume it's just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

> either a, b, c, and d

This means that possible combinations include *ad*, *bd*, and *cd*.

> either a, b, c, or d
>   any one of a, b, c, or d

Both of these mean that the possibilities are limited to a, b, c, or d.

Comment: Yes, that was how I initially had read it. I was figuring that the commas were instead of *or*, so we get one of a, b, c in combination (and) with d.

Comment: If it truly means what you say, then I would suggest repunctuating: _either a, b, or c; and d_