# Meaning of “either”: “not /A or B/” = “not /either A or B/”?

Tags: conjunctions, negation, logic

In a positive sentence, "either . . .or" is sometimes used to express an exclusive disjunction.

However, what happens when “either” is used in negation, as in sentence two below? Is the meaning the same as in sentence one?

> 1: John is not in the kitchen or the bedroom.

This sentence indicates that John is not in the kitchen and John is not in the bedroom.

> 2: John is not in either the kitchen or the bedroom.

This sentence indicates what?

Comment: Sentence 2 does not make sense. You already know that someone can't be in two places at once, so of course he is not in the kitchen, or not in the bedroom. That goes without saying.

Comment: By the way, sentence one can be rewritten with "neither" ... "nor".

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/does-either-a-or-b-preclude-both-a-and-b

Comment: @MrLister It does make sense - you could say "John is not in either the kitchen or the bedroom. He is in the bathroom".

Comment: Logically, _either_ is just another form of _or_; its use is irrelevant in logic and is ignored. Syntactically, it's a phrase marker denoting the first of a series of disjuncts, which is most likely to be of length 2. Finally, NOT (_A_ OR _B_) is equivalent to (NOT _A_) AND (NOT _B_) by [De Morgan's Laws](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sentence 2 means the same as Sentence 1, it's just a clumsier, more long-winded way of putting it. The use of 'either' etc. is somewhat redundant, but still technically valid. As Mr Lister points out 'neither' ... 'nor' could be used, and would be more common.