# "or" versus "xor" in English

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

If *a* said to *b* "do this or that", would *b* be disobeying *a* if it did both?
In others words, in English is "or" the same as xor, the exclusive or?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does "either A or B " preclude "both A and B"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/does-either-a-or-b-preclude-both-a-and-b). Another one (not relying on the specific word "either") is [Use of “Or”, inclusive or exclusive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95624/use-of-or-inclusive-or-exclusive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OR it is not exclusive.

To get the exclusive OR, you say: "*either ... or*"

But check out (Exclusive "or" in English):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

for more insight